# Date difference get different results from function than from select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I need to get the difference of 2 date fields, if the greater date is null then I'll use `SYSDATE` instead. Having this requirement, I created a function to solve this issues (note: this code follows the standard of the organization, not my personal taste)

```
CREATE FUNCTION F_GET_DIFFERENCE (P_WORKFLOWID NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER --result in minutes
IS
    TIME NUMBER;
BEGIN
    TIME := 0
    SELECT
        F_WORKTIME_DIFF(NVL(X.ENDDATE, SYSDATE), X.STARTDATE)
    INTO
        TIME
    FROM
        TABLEX X
    WHERE
        X.WORKFLOWID = P_WORKFLOWID;

    RETURN TIME;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RETURN 0;
END;
```

The `F_WORKTIME_DIFF` function already exists and calculates the worktime of the day (assumming nobody works at 12 a.m. and things like that). The problem is when calling this function, the result contains an additional amount of time. That's very strange, because when executing the query in the function, it returns the expected output.

Example (important: date format in Peru is *DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS*)

```
TABLEX

WORKFLOWID        STARTDATE                ENDDATE
    1             '01/12/2012 10:00:00'      null
```

Assumming that the server day is the same day (01/12/2012) but greater time (10:01:00), we execute the function:

```
SELECT F_GET_DIFFERENCE(1)
FROM DUAL;
```

The result is: 14.

Now, executing the query in the function and having the server time at 10:02:00, the result is 2 (exact output).

I even tried executing this

```
SELECT
    F_WORKTIME_DIFF(NVL(X.ENDDATE, SYSDATE), X.STARTDATE) SELECT_WAY,
    F_GET_DIFFERENCE(1) FUNCTION_WAY
FROM
    TABLEX X
WHERE
    X.WORKFLOWID = 1
```

And the result is (having the server time at 10:10:00)

```
SELECT_WAY    FUNCTION_WAY
    10             24
```

Is maybe any consideration that I must take into account when working with Oracle dates in inner functions or anything that could explain this odd behavior?

Comment: Throw a stone and hide the hand? Please at least post why the downvote.

Comment: Another *just want to downvote your question by no means* with no comment?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to tell anything without seeing the function F_WORKTIME_DIFF.
Whatever is the datatype returned from F_WORKTIME_DIFF, it is casted to `number` when assigned to the variable `time`. This may be a clue.

Comment: If you check my last example, I use the `F_WORKTIME_DIFF` function inside the `F_GET_DIFFERENCE` function and outside it in the select statement, and I get 2 different results, what makes me think this method isn't involved in the wrong output.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly what are you looking for but the first example gives you hours diff between two dates:

```
Select EXTRACT(HOUR FROM (SYSDATE - trunc(SYSDATE )) DAY TO SECOND ) From dual
/

Select
  EXTRACT(hour   From Cast(SYSDATE as timestamp)) hh,
  EXTRACT(minute From Cast(SYSDATE as timestamp)) mi,
  EXTRACT(second From Cast(SYSDATE as timestamp)) ss
From dual
/
```